# Cannot deserialize HTTP Response to a POJO class. throwing out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, serialization, httpresponse, pojo, rest-assured

i have an api call which will response as below. Now i wanted to deserialize to a pojo class. Any suggestions appreciated.

Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 470,
    "shipmentId": "1497",
  },
  {
    "id": 471,
    "shipmentId": "1498",
  }
]
```

My Pojo class named TripHandlerShipmentsResponse.java looks like below.

```
@Data
public class TripHandlerShipmentsResponse {

  private List<Object> response;

}
```

Now here I'm trying to deserialize the response

```
return httpResponse.deserialize(TripHandlerShipmentsResponse.class);
```

But i was getting below kind of error.

```
Cannot deserialize instance of `Mypackage.TripHandlerShipmentsResponse` out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: (String)"[{"id":470, .............
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response model is wrong . Create model with same skeleton of json response .

You have to pass type as array or list in mapper

Comment: private Object[] response;